# Passing parameters to a OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Why is the following query does not work? It gives me error: **Incorrect syntax near '+'.**

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #tmpTable
FROM OPENQUERY("127.0.0.1", 'EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory' +  @StoreId + ',' + @StartDate ',' +  @EndDate)
```

How should I be passing the parameters `@StoreId`  `@StartDate` and  `@EndDate` to make it work correctly? Thanks.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` does not accept expressions, only string constants. You can pass parameters to a remote stored procedure "cleanly" (i.e. without building strings and involving type conversions), but then you should use `EXECUTE ... AT` and use the `?` syntax for parameters.

Comment: Just realised this is relevant here: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OPENQUERY` requires a literal; it can't be an expression. If you need to pass parameters. one method is using dynamic SQL, but it can get "ugly". This is incomplete, as what we have is however

```
DECLARE @StoreId int = 7,
        @StartDate date = '20190101',
        @EndDate date = '20190701';
--Values shoukd be set

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'{SELECT Statement parts}' + @CRLF + 
           N'FROM OPENQUERY("172.16.111.11", N''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,112),'''') + ',' +  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,112),'''') +') OQ';

PRINT @SQL; --Your best Friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Therefore an alternative methhod is using `EXECUTE ... AT`, which requires a linked server:

```
EXEC (N'[DB].dbo.SP_inventory ?, ?, ?;',@StoreId, @StartDate, @EndDate) AT [{Linked Server Name}];
```

Comment: Then how can I use the `EXEC (N'[DB].dbo.SP_inventory ?, ?, ?;',@StoreId, @StartDate, @EndDate) AT [{Linked Server Name}];` with `SELECT` into a temp table?

Comment: Note that if the stored procedure involved also lives on a SQL Server, you can use `@param1 = ?, @param2 = ?, ...` to assign the parameter values by name, rather than ordinal position, which is more robust. (The same applies to the original query, of course.)

Comment: The reason I wanted to use  `OPENQUERY` was that, I wanted to use it with a `SELECT` statement after `FROM` keyword for inserting the returned values from the stored procedure to a temp table. The solution you gave me does not work after `FROM`.

Comment: If you know the structure of the result set, you can use `INSERT .. EXEC AT` (with some caveats, see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/193727/97345)). If you cannot rely on the structure of the result set, cobbling together a text-based dynamic query with `OPENQUERY` is your only recourse. This can get very ugly, however, as you need either a global temp table, or lift your entire query into a dynamic one.

Comment: I can't figure it out how to use apostrophe to format my `OPENQUERY` statement, the same logic from your first example applied on my query just not work, I can't create a valid string. I created something like this; `OPENQUERY("172.16.111.11", N'EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate)) + ',' +  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate)))`

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can't figure it out how to use apostrophe"*, @OzanYurtsever?

Comment: @Larnu, I mean the quotation marks for the query string. It does not work because I am placing quotations out of order and can't figure out how to put them in order.

Comment: An **internal** IP doesn't expose anything, @B3S .It certainly isn't "sensitive".

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "placing quotation marks out of order". Perhaps if you provided full SQL Statement I would be able to help you further.

Comment: I could argue that internal IP's are sensitive and they expose to risks, but anyhow i don't see the point on sharing them @Larnu

Comment: Fixed the issue in regards to the missing trailing quote you asked about in a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957696/cant-figure-out-the-correct-quotation-mark-structure-for-a-sql-string), @OzanYurtsever. You need to replace the entire part in the braces, including them. I've also added your best friend to help you debug.

Comment: @Larnu, The other errors have been gone but there is one last error. `Incorrect syntax near '20170101'.` The value "20170101" is given for the parameter `@StartDate`.

Comment: What does your best friend say? Don't forget, i can't run your SQL, so tghis is far harder for me to debug.

Comment: It says; `SELECT * INTO #tmpTable
FROM OPENQUERY("172.16.111.11", N'EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory_count8005,'20170101','20190101'') OQ`

Comment: lack of a space between `count` and `8005` @OzanYurtsever. I fixed that earliesr when iw as making edits. the `PRINT`, like I said, will help you; as you *should* be able to easily debug that. If you can't, then you shouldn't be using this and should be getting someone more familiar with T-SQL to implement these things; as that is very simple typographical error to fix.

Comment: @Larnu, I have added the space but same error occurs. Here is the sql; `SELECT * INTO #tmpTable
FROM OPENQUERY("172.16.111.11", N'EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory 8005,'20170101','20190101'') OQ` Incorrect syntax near '20170101'.