# Can't figure out the correct quotation mark structure for a sql string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use `OPENQUERY` with dynamic variables. I tried to create a query string like this;

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'{SELECT * INTO #tmpTable}' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM OPENQUERY("my_source_ip", ''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,112)) + ',' +  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,112)) +')';
```

However, I have got following errors;

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '{'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '}'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory8005,[20170101],[20190707]'.
```

How can I fix this query string to work correctly? Thanks.

Comment: [Background context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57956543/4137916).

Comment: @Jeroen Mosters, I am still struggling with it. There is something wrong with the order of quotation marks.

Comment: What is my_source_ip, where does it come from?

Comment: You left the braces (`{}`) in there... I used those to as you omitted your SQL statement in your *other* question so I represented it with `N'{SELECT Statement parts}'`. The error is literally telling you the problem.

Comment: As for the other part, I have added the missing trailing quote in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "," after stored procedure name. I have replaced it with blank space. Please try this.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'{SELECT * INTO #tmpTable}' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM OPENQUERY("my_source_ip", ''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory' +  
CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ' ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,112)) + ',' 
+  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,112)) +')';
```