# Using a temporary table on SRSS report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure which works without a problem at the sql server side. However, when I feed a SRSS report with this stored procedure, I am having an error such as; **Invalid object name '##tempTable'.**

Here is my stored procedure;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Link_SP_Inventory]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StoreId int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS


BEGIN

DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(MAX);

SET @QUERY = N'SELECT * INTO ##tempTable ' + 
           N'FROM OPENQUERY("172.11.111.11", N''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ','  + '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,112),'''') + '''' + ',' +  '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,112) + '''','''') + ')';

           EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY;


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM ##tempTable
    drop table ##tempTable
END

GO
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: [Backstory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956320/passing-parameters-to-a-openquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Table referenced in a Dynamic statement can only be referenced inside that dynamic statement. Take this simple query:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS I INTO #temp;';

SELECT *
FROM #temp;
```

Notice the statement fails with:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 
>   Invalid object name '#temp'.

It seems, however, you don't need to temporary table, and this will work fine:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Link_SP_Inventory]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StoreId int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS


BEGIN

    DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @QUERY = N'SELECT * ' + 
                N'FROM OPENQUERY("172.11.111.11", N''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ','  + '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),@StartDate,112),'''') + '''' + ',' +  '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),@EndDate,112) + '''','''') + ')';

    EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY;

END;
```

Comment: Perfect, but now I can't take the columns into SRSS report. I have got a dataset without any columns inside while parameters loaded succesfully.

Comment: Did you give SSRS default values when you refreshed the columns?

Comment: Do you mean the default values for the parameters?

Comment: No, when you refresh the columns, you'll get a pop-up asking you the values to get the column for the dataset. Otherwise you'll need to define your columns in your dataset manually in SSRS.

Comment: I did not get that pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Link_SP_Inventory]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StoreId int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS


BEGIN

    DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(MAX);

SET @QUERY = N'SELECT * INTO ##temp_global ' + 
       N'FROM OPENQUERY("172.11.111.11", N''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ','  + '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,112),'''') '''' + ',' +  '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,112) + '''','''') + ')';


 EXECUTE (@QUERY)

 SELECT * FROM ##temp_global

 DROP TABLE ##temp_global
END
```

Comment: what is `##temp_global`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this once and I had to create the temp table initially with the column names specified and then insert into it, so that your dataset would be able to pick up the column names. So something like this may work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Link_SP_Inventory]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StoreId int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS


BEGIN

DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(MAX);

CREATE TABLE ##tempTable ([ColumnOne] VARCHAR(10), [ColumnTwo] DATETIME) --Add required columns here

SET @QUERY = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("172.11.111.11", N''EXEC [DB].dbo.SP_inventory ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),@StoreId) + ','  + '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@StartDate,112),'''') + '''' + ',' +  '''' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar,@EndDate,112) + '''','''') + ')';

INSERT INTO ##tempTable ([ColumnOne],[ColumnTwo])
EXEC (@QUERY);


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM ##tempTable
DROP TABLE ##tempTable
END

GO
```